# Why return keyword is used as a method?

Tags: javascript

I was going through the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#iterating_over_async_iterables) and found this code:

```
const LIMIT = 3;

const asyncIterable = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    let i = 0;
    return {
      next() {
        const done = i === LIMIT;
        const value = done ? undefined : i++;
        return Promise.resolve({ value, done });
      },
      return() {
        // This will be reached if the consumer called 'break' or 'return' early in the loop.
        return { done: true };
      },
    };
  },
};

(async () => {
  for await (const num of asyncIterable) {
    console.log(num);
  }
})();
// 0
// 1
// 2
```

In the code above, I'm not able to understand why return used as a method like this `return(){}`? I tried running this code and worked fine. So, is this a new addition to JavaScript?

Comment: Because that's how an [async iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_async_iterator_and_async_iterable_protocols) is specified: _"`return(value)` Optional: A function that accepts zero or one argument and returns a promise. The promise fulfills to an object conforming to the `IteratorResult` interface, and the properties have the same semantics as those of the sync iterator's."_

Comment: Thank you @Andreas Din't taken care of that optional but it's misleading concept in JavaScript I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [method definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions), not a return statement.

Similar to how, here, `return` is a property of `object`:

```js
const object = {
    return: () => {
        return "Hello world";
    }
};

console.log(object.return()); // Hello world
```

Comment: _"It's an object property, not a return statement."_ - OP already knows this: _"I'm not able to understand why return **used as a method**..."_

Comment: I don't get that impression from OP. They understand it's a method but doesn't understand why, considering the `return keyword` in the title. My understanding of the question is OP asking why `return` can be used as a function name.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74954309/why-return-keyword-is-used-as-a-method#comment132270941_74954327) @Andreas Just because it's in a specification doesn't mean that it's not a bad naming convention. I would argue that any overlap with language keywords is — at best — potentially confusing to _some developers_ (case in point: this question)

Comment: @jsejcksn In this case, it's a good naming convention. On generator objects, this method does exactly what the name says, similar to the `.throw()` method they also have.

Comment: I think this discussion proves that it's an opinion based naming convention. Which is fair and I removed my original note from the answer.